# Formula to convert from lat/lng to EPSG:27700?

Tags: geometry

Anyone know how to convert from lat/lng to EPSG:27700?

Answer (score 1):

you can refer this link

http://www.ehow.com/how_5169102_convert-latitude-longitude-gps-coordinates.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Mouse-position-in-lat-long-td5567114.html

May be useful